# Watir: How to define links within <li> container and click

Tags: selenium, watir

[image: dom]

I need to define these 3 links using Watir and to be able to click on each link.
These are all attributes I have (screenshot attached)

something like: 
`el(:test) { b.link(href: '/Categories/Makeup/Lips/c/A300') }`
doesn't work

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work" means? Is there an exception and/or what is the behaviour you see? The `href` you have in the example, doesn't match any of the elements in the image, which could be the problem.

Comment: sorry uploaded wrong screenshot. Assume `hrefs` are matching. Error is: `pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PDP::Functional>)> @pdp.test
=> #<Watir::Anchor: located: false; {:href=>"/Categories/Makeup/Lips/c/A300", :tag_name=>"a"}>
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PDP::Functional>)> @pdp.test.present?
=> false` It's just not seeing it

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out, thanks
`el(:test) { b.li(text: 'Lips') }`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is `el` a page object method? Which page-object library is it from?

Comment: it's an alias from our framework: https://github.com/azohra/ferris/blob/master/lib/ferris/concepts/elements.rb